# Having trouble overriting bootstrap's css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble overriding bootstrap's css code. 
I have included my own stylesheet AFTER bootstrap's code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I know that a soft override like simply having a style.css that reads:

```
a {
    color: #c54bb7; (it's a sort of red)
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

probably won't work as bootstrap has more specific css that has priority over that one. However, you can see in this picture the link text is green because of the simple a{} config in bootstrap, and that's it. Which means mine should have priority, as it is after the bootstrap css, correct? I'm not sure what i am doing wrong here. I want all links to be red.

https://i.gyazo.com/bf06b0a3990927ed019bf65873a84d42.png

Comment: place your css below bootstrap css and things will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use '!important' to force overriding.

```
a {
   color: #c54bb7 !important; (it's a sort of red)
   text-decoration: none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `!important`. `!important` emphasizes that this specific css should be applied and overrides the bootstrap css.

```
a {
    color: #c54bb7; !important
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: If you liked my answer, would you mind giving me an upvote, it helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

use a wrapper div for your entire html code

like

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="content_area">

content goes here...

</div>

</div>
```

and style using the wrapper class,

```
.wrapper a{
 color: #c54bb7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```